# timeout while snmpbulkwalking with pysnmp

Tags: python, snmp, pysnmp

Here is my snmpbulkwalk implementation (took it from examples):

```
def bulk_walk(self, oid, context, conv):
walkdone = False
data = list()

if context:
    community = "%s@%s" % (self.community, context)
else:
    community = self.community

for errorIndication, \
    errorStatus, errorIndex, \
    varBinds in bulkCmd(SnmpEngine(),
                        CommunityData(community),
                        UdpTransportTarget((self.ip, self.port)),
                        ContextData(), 0, 10,
                        ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(oid)), lookupMib=False):

    if errorIndication:
        raise(SNMPError(errorIndication))
    elif errorStatus:
        raise(SNMPError('%s at %s' % (
                errorStatus.prettyPrint(),
                errorIndex and varBinds[int(errorIndex)-1][0] or '?'
             ))
        )
    else:
        for varBind in varBinds:
            print(varBind[0].prettyPrint(),  conv(varBind[1]))
            if not varBind[0].prettyPrint().startswith(oid+"."):
                walkdone = True
                break
            data.append( (varBind[0].prettyPrint(),  conv(varBind[1])) )
    if walkdone:
        break
return(data)
```

I am trying to snmpwalk OID that does not exists, when I trying to do it with snmpbulkwalk I am getting:

$ snmpwalk  -v2c -c public@1 10.253.35.61 1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.1

```
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.17.4.3.1.1 = No Such Instance currently exists at this OID
```

If we look at tcpdump we can see this:

```
11:26:00.460905 IP host.52491 > 10.253.35.61.snmp:  C=public@1 GetBulk(30)  N=0 M=10 17.4.3.1.1
11:26:01.462162 IP host.52491 > 10.253.35.61.snmp:  C=public@1 GetBulk(30)  N=0 M=10 17.4.3.1.1
11:26:01.658323 IP 10.253.35.61.snmp > host.52491:  C=public@1 GetResponse(215)  17.4.4.1.1.1414=1414 17.4.4.1.1.4103=4103 17.4.4.1.1.4104=4104 17.4.4.1.1.4115=4115 17.4.4.1.1.4136=4136 17.4.4.1.1.4137=4137 17.4.4.1.2.1414=1500 17.4.4.1.2.4103=1500 17.4.4.1.2.4104=1500 17.4.4.1.2.4115=1500
11:26:01.658561 IP host.52491 > 10.253.35.61.snmp:  C=public@1 GetRequest(30)  17.4.3.1.1
11:26:01.659643 IP 10.253.35.61.snmp > host.52491:  C=public@1 GetResponse(215)  17.4.4.1.1.1414=1414 17.4.4.1.1.4103=4103 17.4.4.1.1.4104=4104 17.4.4.1.1.4115=4115 17.4.4.1.1.4136=4136 17.4.4.1.1.4137=4137 17.4.4.1.2.1414=1500 17.4.4.1.2.4103=1500 17.4.4.1.2.4104=1500 17.4.4.1.2.4115=1500
11:26:01.660698 IP 10.253.35.61.snmp > host.52491:  C=public@1 GetResponse(30)  17.4.3.1.1=[noSuchInstance]
```

which is ok, I can see error and work around it, but when I query it from pysnmp - am getting "No SNMP response received before timeout" error, and here is tcpdump:

```
11:26:58.497144 IP host.54615 > 10.253.35.61.snmp:  C=public@1 GetBulk(29)  N=0 M=25 17.4.3.1.1
11:26:59.499136 IP host.54615 > 10.253.35.61.snmp:  C=public@1 GetBulk(29)  N=0 M=25 17.4.3.1.1
11:27:00.480834 IP 10.253.35.61.snmp > host.54615:  C=public@1 GetResponse(542)  17.4.4.1.1.1414=1414 17.4.4.1.1.4103=4103 17.4.4.1.1.4104=4104 17.4.4.1.1.4115=4115 17.4.4.1.1.4136=4136 17.4.4.1.1.4137=4137 17.4.4.1.2.1414=1500 17.4.4.1.2.4103=1500 17.4.4.1.2.4104=1500 17.4.4.1.2.4115=1500 17.4.4.1.2.4136=1500 17.4.4.1.2.4137=1500 17.4.4.1.3.1414=14191348 17.4.4.1.3.4103=371017501 17.4.4.1.3.4104=43993868 17.4.4.1.3.4115=379731251 17.4.4.1.3.4136=2614818874 17.4.4.1.3.4137=3830362616 17.4.4.1.4.1414=390518443 17.4.4.1.4.4103=547088805 17.4.4.1.4.4104=270695068 17.4.4.1.4.4115=2723143051 17.4.4.1.4.4136=2811735791 17.4.4.1.4.4137=102796762 17.4.4.1.5.1414=0
11:27:00.503200 IP host.54615 > 10.253.35.61.snmp:  C=public@1 GetBulk(29)  N=0 M=25 17.4.3.1.1
11:27:01.505277 IP host.54615 > 10.253.35.61.snmp:  C=public@1 GetBulk(29)  N=0 M=25 17.4.3.1.1
11:27:02.469848 IP 10.253.35.61.snmp > host.54615:  C=public@1 GetResponse(542)  17.4.4.1.1.1414=1414 17.4.4.1.1.4103=4103 17.4.4.1.1.4104=4104 17.4.4.1.1.4115=4115 17.4.4.1.1.4136=4136 17.4.4.1.1.4137=4137 17.4.4.1.2.1414=1500 17.4.4.1.2.4103=1500 17.4.4.1.2.4104=1500 17.4.4.1.2.4115=1500 17.4.4.1.2.4136=1500 17.4.4.1.2.4137=1500 17.4.4.1.3.1414=14191348 17.4.4.1.3.4103=371017846 17.4.4.1.3.4104=43994108 17.4.4.1.3.4115=380963114 17.4.4.1.3.4136=2616771624 17.4.4.1.3.4137=3830710704 17.4.4.1.4.1414=390519877 17.4.4.1.4.4103=547090599 17.4.4.1.4.4104=270696594 17.4.4.1.4.4115=2724485940 17.4.4.1.4.4136=2813399966 17.4.4.1.4.4137=102954755 17.4.4.1.5.1414=0
11:27:02.987802 IP host.54615 > 10.253.35.61.snmp:  C=public@1 GetBulk(29)  N=0 M=25 17.4.3.1.1
11:27:03.989765 IP host.54615 > 10.253.35.61.snmp:  C=public@1 GetBulk(29)  N=0 M=25 17.4.3.1.1
```

and this is bad, because there are could be different scenarios that can cause timeout (host down, wrong community string, etc), how can I emulate snmpbulkwalk behavior with pysnmp, possibly without going to lower level API.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Second capture shows missing GetResponse packets. Assuming timeouts do occur due to slow agent, consider making pysnmp waiting longer and possibly retrying less:

```
...
UdpTransportTarget(('demo.snmplabs.com', 161), timeout=8.0, retries=0),
...
```

If it is rather a connectivity issue, try retrying more aggressively:

```
...
UdpTransportTarget(('demo.snmplabs.com', 161), timeout=1.0, retries=5),
...
```

Also note that in pysnmp capture (but not in code) you request 25 variables in response where snmpbulkwalk wants just 10. Too many variables may stress your agent.

Comment: That not it, snmpbulkwalk switching from GetBulk to GetResponse after first timeout. pysnmp continue with GetBulk until timeout.

Comment: GET and GETBULK are different command, SNMP does not mandate them to be used together. If you want to emulate snmpbulkwalk, you could make your Python script calling getCmd() along with bulkCmd(). To address your original concern: pysnmp does not mix timeout with no-such-oid error condition. The library reports whichever occurs and does not mask or substitute any errors.